# php-mysqlnd or php-mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, ubuntu-12.04

Long story short: just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (Debian based), nginx, php-fpm and mysql. Now I need the MySQL driver for PHP, but which should I choose?

Which is better php-mysqlnd or php-mysql?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**php-mysqlnd** is the better choice. It is a drop-in replacement for the **php-mysql** extension. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) you can find more information about it.

Excerpt from the above-mentioned link:

The mysqlnd library is highly optimized for and tightly integrated into PHP. The MySQL Client Library cannot offer the same optimizations because it is a general-purpose client library.

The mysqlnd library is using PHP internal C infrastructure for seamless integration into PHP. In addition, it is using PHP memory management, PHP Streams (I/O abstraction) and PHP string handling routines. The use of PHP memory management by mysqlnd allows, for example, memory savings by using read-only variables (copy on write) and makes mysqlnd apply to PHP memory limits. Additional advantages include:

- Powerful plugin API to extend feature set
- Asynchronous, non-blocking queries
- 150+ performance statistics
- Powerful plugins